# Blank screen in windows 7 after update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, blank-screen

I have updated my `Windows 7 Professional 64 bit` OS. But after restart it started showing a blank screen with a message box saying "Personalized Settings" as shown below:

[image]

I thought to kill this process using Task Manager, so I pressed `Ctrl+Del+Alt` and opened Task Manager and killed process `personalised.exe` but after that message box disappear but showing the blank screen.

I have the following processes in my Task Manager:

[image]

Please advise what could be the reason for this and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: You allow it to finish.  That would require you to restart your computer.  Explorer.exe isn't even running which is the reason you don't have a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In the Task Manager menu, click on *File/New Task (run...)*, then type "Explorer".

If your desktop icons appear you must use FixWin v 1.2.exe tools to fix this problem. But if nothing is  shown you must uninstall updates.

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer? What does FixWin do? What update must be uninstalled?